# Accessing ViewModel by inheriting a View in MvvmCross

Tags: c#, inheritance, mvvm, viewmodel, mvvmcross

I want to access my ViewModel from a class which is not the View. Is it OK if I do the following? Is this breaking the pattern?

```
namespace MyApp
{
   public class GameView
   {
        protected new GameViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get { return (GameViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
        }
   }
}

// Derived class
namespace MyApp
{
    public class InAppPurchase: GameView
    {
         public void BuyCoins()
         { 
             ViewModel.PurchasedCoins += ViewModel.CoinsForSale;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is definitely violating the MVVM pattern in my opinion. I think you have a GameView which is bound to GameViewModel. Why do you want to inherit from GameView class? Without knowing the exact scenario, can't explain clearly also.

Comment: This question is primarily opinion based. My opinion is that you should have a 1:1 map of Views to ViewModels. The code you've shown currently violates that and you will probably have to do manual navigation in the View rather than doing it from the ViewModel with your code, in MvvmCross.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a ViewModel from whichever place you want you might want to send messages (MvxMessage) and handle them within the ViewModel (publish/subscribe with IMessenger). This is the proper way to communicate between ViewModels or ViewModels and other components like services in the Mvvm pattern.